# Workday Incremental Extract

Tags: api, workday-api

I am using Informatica Intelligent Cloud Services (IICS) to retrieve Contracts Information(Get_Customer_Contracts). Is it possible to incrementally extract data from Workday using API. Example : Contracts which have been created or updated in the last one day.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what I see in the API documentation there is only a way to get contracts between 2 effective dates and no way to extract based on Creation date.

API Documentation : https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Revenue_Management/v39.0/samples/Get_Customer_Contracts_Request.xml

Unfortunately if you must extract based on creation date, you need to use a RAAS report.